# run jQuery when mouse is heading towards or at top centre of the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to execute a function when the mouse is in the top of the document vertically and the center of the document horizontally ?

What about execute that js code / function as the mouse approaches the top-centre ?

Here is how I would think of doing this ( in jQuery and vanilla js ), but if there is a better way please share:

```
$(document).mousemove(
    function(e){
        if((e.pageY=0) && (e.pageX=)){
            //run function
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I left what e.pageX should be equal to in the condition is that I don't know how to do 50% or the middle.

Also, i believe, this will run the function only when the mouse is exactly at the top and centre.

Does anyone know to gradually execute it as the mouse approaches the top-centre?

Comment: Use the `mousemove` event? But keep in mind that it is a very intensive task, even though it is rate-limited

Comment: have you tried anything? post your code please

Comment: @darshanags I edited the question with the addition of how I would think of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code. Keep in mind that if you do not expect your browser window to resize, then you could assign `$(window).width()/2` to a variable outside the `mousemove` binding as to avoid looking for the window width on each update. Usage of `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` is required to round down/up the calculated horizontal center to avoid decimal numbers.

Example 1 (the horizontal center is dynamic. It will always be recalculated on mouse move):

```
$(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
    if((e.pageY==0) && (e.pageX==Math.floor($(window).width()/2))){
        //run function
    }
});
```

Example 2 (horizontal center remains static, namely the calculated value at the time of execution):

```
var hCenter = Math.floor($(window).width()/2);
$(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
    if((e.pageY==0) && (e.pageX==hCenter)){
        //run function
    }
});
```

Example 3 (update hCenter on window resize):

```
// calculate horizontal center at page load
var hCenter = Math.floor($(window).width()/2);

// update hCenter every time the window is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
    hCenter = Math.floor($(window).width()/2);
});

$(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
    if((e.pageY==0) && (e.pageX==hCenter)){
        //run function
    }
});
```

Comment: what if I wanted to update the value of hCenter each time the window resizes? because I do expect it to resize... is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is super simple solution I just thought of. Put an empty `div` in the HTML, position it properly, make it invisible with `opacity: 0`, and listen `mouseover` event:

```
<div class="detector"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.detector {
    position: absolute; // or fixed, depending on needed behaviour
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.detector').mouseover(function() {
    alert('Mousemove detected!');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhPp8/

Comment: hmmm that is an interesting solution. does cause for more mark-up, but thank you. Any idea on how to alert or run any js code for that matter as the mouse approaches .detector instead of exactly on .detector. Well, not instead of, including.

Comment: in this case you will have to listen `$(document).mousemove` and it makes everything much more complicated.

Comment: @IMUXIxD You don't need to worry about approaching .detector, because you control its size. Make it as big or small as you want to change the area in which a hit is detected. If you want two different events, make two detection areas: `.detector .outside {} .detector .inside {}`.

Comment: @AustinMullins Thank you for explaining that, I just realised that actually while playing the with fiddle. But, thank you.